# Revert .zshrc file to its previous state

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I accidentally override `.zshrc`. The file is now empty. Fyi, I still have one terminal (macos) which loaded its previous configuration. Is it possible to revert it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution to avoid future mistakes, if you are using vim with its proper undo settings you can get back in time:

```
" Reference: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/53/7339
" Let's save undo info!
if !isdirectory($HOME."/.vim")
    call mkdir($HOME."/.vim", "", 0770)
endif
if !isdirectory($HOME."/.vim/undo-dir")
    call mkdir($HOME."/.vim/undo-dir", "", 0700)
endif
set undodir=~/.vim/undo-dir
set undofile
```

Then you can run the `:earlier` command, like this:

```
:earlier 1d
```

For more about this run `:h earlier`

A second solution is to create a git repo with your "dotfiles" and then creating symlinks, like:

```
ln -sfvn ~/.dotfiles/zshrc ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Luckily, the ~/.zshrc.backup file had the previous contents of my .zshrc file. I copied its contents to restore. I suggest checking ~/.zshrc.backup if you haven't closed any tab with previous .zshrc running. (macOS)